# #VALUE! when calling DLL function (C++) in 64-bit Excel

Tags: c++, excel, visual-studio-2013, 32bit-64bit, vba

I am very new to C-plus-plus and trying to use it to create user-defined functions for excel. I wrote a very simple test function in Cpp that just adds two arguments together (Excel cell references).

I compiled a 32-bit DLL & a seperate 64-bit DLL project using the same *.cpp and *.def files in Visual Studio 2013.

When I run the 32-bit DLL on a 32-bit Excel install, the new excel function works fine (eg: 5 + 10 = 15).

When I run the 64-bit DLL on a 64-bit Excel install, I am getting a #VALUE error in the cell.

Can anyone see something blatantly wrong that I am doing with the 64-bit DLL? Thanks!

```
***** VBA (32-bit) *****
Declare Function ExPlus Lib _
"C:\AKH-VSWS\Ex-Plus32\Debug\Ex-Plus32.dll" _
(ByVal a As Double, _
 ByVal b As Double) As Double
```

Computer 1: Windows 7 (64-bit), Office 2016 (32-bit), Visual Studio 2013

```
***** VBA (64-bit) *****
Declare PtrSafe Function ExPlus Lib _
"C:\AKH-VSWS\Ex-Plus64\x64\Debug\Ex-Plus64.dll" _
(ByVal a As Double, _
 ByVal b As Double) As Double
```

Computer 2: Windows 7 (64-bit), Office 2016 (64-bit)

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 12.00.21005.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Dump of file c:\AKH-VSWS\Ex-Plus64\x64\Debug\Ex-Plus64.dll
PE signature found
File Type: DLL

FILE HEADER VALUES
            8664 machine (x64)
               7 number of sections
        5AC930F1 time date stamp Sat Apr 07 16:58:25 2018
               0 file pointer to symbol table
               0 number of symbols
              F0 size of optional header
            2022 characteristics
                   Executable
                   Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses
                   DLL
```

Comment: You cannot use C++ to build a DLL file that exports COM types or C-style functions and have it work in both a 32-bit and 64-bit environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating C++ .dll for use by Excel & C# (32/64bit Window)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309846/creating-c-dll-for-use-by-excel-c-sharp-32-64bit-window)

Comment: @ashleedawg, if I am reading your comment correctly, you are correct. DLL's won't work in voth worlds. I have two seperate VStudio projects. 1 to compile a 32bit DLL. And 1 to compile a seperate 64bit DLL. The 32bit's working as expected, but the 64bit function is returning errors in Excel. I can't figure out if its a compiler error or a VBA error...Suggestions? Where/how to start debugging?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a solution, but it might be a step in the right direction...I happened to stumble over a page today. And the recommended software seems to think that my DLL can not find a dependency (MSVCR120D.DLL). So I'll need to look into this more.

...still open to suggestions, though...

http://access.mvps.org/access/bugs/bugs0019.htm

> This is caused by a missing Dependency file (runtime files) on your
>   machine that's required by the DLL. The error message "File Not Found"
>   is not being generated by the DLL file itself, but Access since it
>   cannot locate the other required DLLs.
>
> To find out if the DLL has any dependencies, you can use one of these
>   two methods...Download Dependency Walker  Search your hard drive for
>   any dependent files and make sure they exist and are registered.

[Dependency Walker screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEC1U.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The plot thickens...

It appears that I have compiled in "debug" mode, and might have to change the Visual Studio setting from "debug" to something else.

[VS2012 MSVCR120D.dll is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114427/vs2012-msvcr120d-dll-is-missing?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

> "...the "D" stands for debug information...The debug DLLs come only
>   with the respective version of Visual Studio and are not meant to be
>   redistributed..."

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out what my issues were...

I was compiling it in debugger mode, so it was adding a "D" onto the name of one of the dependency files. And when I moved the DLL to a computer without Visual Studio, it wouldn't run. I had to switch my compile settings to release mode.

In the *.cpp file, I was missing one of the two underscores (_) in the __stdcall statement. And Visual Studio's debugger and I weren't catching it. So the user-defined-function wasn't being exported with the DLL.

I also didn't properly register / set-up the *.def file within Visual Studio. So even if the __stdcall statement was correct, the function still wouldn't have exported correctly.

And apparently, if you don't somehow register the UDF with excel/windows, you need to run the C++/DLL function through a local VBA function. I have to read up on that (XLL's and all that fun stuff).

So, in conclusion, yeah...I was being stupid.